# Why git rebase is not based on my last pushed commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm working an a branch, I made some commits and pushed them to the corresponding remote branch. Then I tried to rebase to master. Yes, there are conflicts. But when I tried to resolve them, I found that the conflicted files do not contain my last committed(and pushed) changes. Is this a problem? How can I get the last committed changes appear in master?

Comment: Can you share the flow of commands you used? There are too many details missing to provide a useful answer.

Comment: I mad changes on my branch, then I add and committed my changes:
git add changedfile.cpp
git commit -m "some commit msg"
git push
Then I tried to rebase to master
git rebase master

Comment: Sorry about the mess of comment. I don't know how to make the git code in a good format.

Comment: Your should [edit] your post and add the commands you used - you can format them by indenting four spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do git rebase, all your commits from common ancestor between two branches are applied one by one. If one of these commits creates a conflict, then you have to resolve the conflict to continue.
Only after conflict resolution the next commits will be applied. So all your changes after the commit which resulted in conflict wont be there while doing conflict resolution. They will be applied when you continue rebase after conflict resolution using `git rebase --continue`

Comment: Thank you. It helps! In fact, I happened to read about how rebase works early this morning, but I failed to understand it then. Thanks again!